# my raspberry wont let me upgrade

Tags: software-installation, java, apt, update

Every time I try to upgrade I receive the following ouptu:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b23~pre8-2~) but it is not installed
 gvfs-fuse : Depends: gvfs (= 1.12.3-4) but 1.12.3-1+b1 is installed
 openjdk-6-jre-lib : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b17) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I have tried to `install openjdk-6-jre-headless`, however it comes up with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gvfs-fuse : Depends: gvfs (= 1.12.3-4) but 1.12.3-1+b1 is to be installed
 openjdk-6-jre-headless : Depends: tzdata-java but it is not going to be installed

                          Recommends: icedtea-6-jre-cacao (= 6b27-1.12.5-1+rpi1) but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: icedtea-6-jre-jamvm (= 6b27-1.12.5-1+rpi1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

`apt-get -f` makes no difference to the response.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to remove the partially-installed applications. then you can continue:

```
sudo apt-get remove default-jre-headless gvfs-fuse
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: it still replys with the same.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove default-jre-headless gvfs-fuse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates-java : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b16-1.6.1-2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 java6-runtime-headless
 openjdk-6-jre-lib : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b17) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages

Comment: @raspberry911 you need to keep removing the half-installed pieces, e.g. you will now need `sudo apt-get remove  ca-certificates-java java6-runtime-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib` and try again. You may need to do this several times (sounds like a lot of bits installed without dependencies).

Comment: @raspberry911 Will it let you manually install the missing dependencies?

Comment: no it will outputsudo apt-get remove ca-certificates-java java6-runtime-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'java6-runtime-headless' can't be removed"